# Is it an offense to attack someone with a toy water pistol?

Tags: united-kingdom, assault

If someone started yelling and swearing at you on the bus can you pull a water gum and spray water in their face? or maybe do it with a bottle of water.

Would you get arrested for that?

[image]

Comment: It is most definitely a crime to assault someone. Whether it be with water, a soft pillow or a gentle Pat on the back. In Boot Camp there were several individuals charged with assault in my squad for simply touching another person innocently.

Comment: If someone is already yelling and swearing at you, then pulling out this water gun and spraying them is likely to be a very, very unhealthy action. You could also be quite sure that your water gun would accidentally fall on the ground and that several people would accidentally step on it.

Comment: @gnasher729 In this country people yell and swear and get verbally abusive but most of them think twice before using their fists. I am after a way to revenge without breaking the law. If police can use water why cant I?

Comment: You are not the police. And "most of them" is no good if you run into the one idiot who carries a knife and doesn't want to look like a coward in front of his friends. If it happened to me, I can assure you that I would stop you and that you wouldn't be able to do it again.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'd rather get stabbed instead of standing there doing nothing but receiving insults, in the same time I would never break the law and attack first.

Comment: You would rather get stabbed? Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a crime and a tort.  Battery.  If you touch a person with something you cause to contact them rather than with your fist, for example, you have still committed the crime and tort.

I remember reading one extreme case where I believe a tortfeasor was found liable (i.e. it was a civil case and he was sued and had to pay damages) for battery for blowing smoke in someone's face.

There may also be some creating-a-commotion or having-liquid-on-the-bus-without-a-lid or other random laws and rules implicated in your example.

Comment: Was the tortfeasor found liable because smoke is toxic, as opposite to water which clearly is not?

Comment: No, it was because the smoke was particulate matter which they deliberately caused to come into contact with the other person.